# Twitter Card not working in Rails 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, meta-tags

I made Rails app and released.
I set ogp and twitter card by using meta-tags gem.
However,Twitter Cards Validator could not find any meta tags.

The browser shows codes blow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>美味しい和菓子が見つかるメディア | MOMIJI</title>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="description" content="美味しい和菓子が見つかるメディア">
<meta name="keywords" content="和菓子, スイーツ, momiji">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://momiji.work/articles">
<meta property="og:title" content="MOMIJI">
<meta property="og:description" content="美味しい和菓子が見つかるメディア">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://momiji.work/articles">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://momiji.work/assets/wa_1.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MOMIJI">
<meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="MOMIJI">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="美味しい和菓子が見つかるメディア">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://momiji.work/assets/wa_1.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Justin0370">
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="jcjt5ya59ZrydFwnxiBcOdi7w3O5sXXSe6QXktFwt6uygvwi/DYmaTgV0yx0HbP/P8l1Zvsz5x5APEjlzsfE5A==" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-c4248fae82b61852d60924641256d5953280f16c38ed2795e77c3a303f6fa588.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<script src="/assets/application-0d8e513de520a20d78d2ba43d84d1c021d3937e16f681fee552500eb92297b4e.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Twitter Card Validator shows

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
WARN:  No metatags found
```

If you can know why my app can't show twitter card, answer this question, please.

Comment: Ruby version: Ruby 2.5.0

Comment: Rails 5.1.4 and Using Heroku

Comment: site url: http://momiji.work/

Comment: Your site returns HTTP 406 not acceptable when fetched with the Twitter Cards user agent.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I do not. You'll need to look at the web server configuration I think.

Comment: Thanks! I gonna search about HTTP 406 and heroku!